# Titanium - Store information in annotation

Tags: iphone, annotations, titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator

I am making multiple annotations on a mapview and I am opening a new detailWindow for the right button selection. I should show some information in the detailWindow via labels and the information to be shown are different for each pin annotation. How could I store some data to the pin annotation? Help me to make this work. Thanks in advance.

This is my code..
Annotation creation:

```
    okBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Text = " + textField.value);
        mapview.removeAllAnnotations();
        Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(textField.value, function(e) {
            var annotations = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var pin = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
                    latitude : e.latitude-i,
                    longitude : e.longitude-i,
                    animate : true,
                    pincolor : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
                    rightButton : Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE//'rightButton.png'
                });
                annotations[i] = pin;
                // suppose mapView is your map object
                mapview.addAnnotation(annotations[i]);
            }
            var region = {
                latitude : e.latitude,
                longitude : e.longitude,
                animate : true,
                latitudeDelta : 0.15,
                longitudeDelta : 0.15
            };
            mapview.setLocation(region);
            Ti.API.info(e);
        });
    });
var detailWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : "#fff",
    navBarHidden : true,
    backgroundImage : 'screen.png'
});
var detailTitle = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color : '#EC6512',
    font : {
        fontSize : 18,
        fontWeight : 'bold',
        fontFamily : 'Arial'
    },
    left : 12,
    top : 60,
    height : 80,
    width : 300,
    clickName : 'detailTitle',
});
detailWindow.add(detailTitle);
```

I should add the text to the `detailTitle` label in the rightButtonEvent.

rightButton event:

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if(evt.clicksource == 'rightButton') {
        Titanium.API.info('Right button clicked');
        navGroup.open(detailWindow);
    };
});
```

I need to create a label and send a data to display in the label.

Comment: Please show that code so that i can suggest you the solution. Both the annotaion creation and right button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store data in the pin you can do this in your loop, set a new property say data in annotation, and set your data array there say : **`{ title, subTitle,...}`**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    var pin = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude : e.latitude-i,
        longitude : e.longitude-i,
    data:data
        animate : true,
        pincolor : Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
        rightButton : Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE//'rightButton.png'
    });
    annotations[i] = pin;
    // suppose mapView is your map object
    mapview.addAnnotation(annotations[i]);
}
```

To acces this data in click event and similarly pass it to your window:

```
mapview.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if(evt.clicksource == 'rightButton') {
        Titanium.API.info('Right button clicked');
        var data = evt.annotation.data;
        detailWindow.data = data;
        navGroup.open(detailWindow);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zeeshan for your reply. I am a beginner in Titanium Studio. So, could you explain how to add a data to `data`. I have edited my question with more code now. I need to display a text in the detailTitle label. How could I make this happen?

Comment: Where is your data which you need to show? Do you have any? Do you show it in pins or not?

Comment: If you have different title for every annotation pin, just make data array with list of titles and add those in for loop like  `data:data[i]`